# Setting Language doesn't work on installed application

Tags: c#, winforms

C# WinForm Application is dual language on frmMain  using two resx files owned by frmMain.

Retrieves info from registry then makes decision which language to use.

Works in IDE but the frmMain displays in English in the  installed application.

The thread culture setting code is being reached. 
The FrmMain resx files are present in the install directory.
The install was done on the development machine with administrator rights.
Any thoughts on what could cause this would be appreciated.

```
 public frmMain(string sApplication):base(sApplication)
    {

        const string french = "SupFrench";

        string culture = ClsLang.PrimaryLangIpf;
        clsLogger.WriteInfoLog("PrimaryLangIpf is " + culture);
        if (culture==french
        {
            clsLogger.WriteInfoLog("Setting Culture to French");//**WE GET HERE**
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", false);
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = 
new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR", false);
        }


        InitializeComponent();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the FrmMain resx file to be in the install folder, you need the fr-FR subfolder containing your *.resources.dll file(s) instead.
See also: [Create a Localized Version of a Resource File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa992030%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)